# DJI Simulation[dji-sdk]

Tags: dji-sdk

I am a Software Engineer student,
I am developing a project which involve a DJI Matrice 200,
I would like to know if there is a way to run a simulation of the drown without the actual drown?
Thanks
Zahi

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you can not run simulation of any DJI drones without the actual drone and it's RC present.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late now but this was released at Airworks https://www.dji.com/simulator